# Back Handler not being triggered in React Native Android Emulator

Tags: react-native

```
const backButtonHandler = (): boolean => {
    console.log('BACK PRESSED!!!!!')
    Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
    return true
}

useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('enters effect');
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backButtonHandler);
    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backButtonHandler);
}, []);
```

I am trying to get this code going. However, backButtonHandler is not being triggered. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: back button will not work if you return true

Comment: Returning false isn't workin either.